# Die Fenster dürfen nicht geklettert sein?

Tags: modal-verb

I'm writing a text and I want to say that "the windows cannot be climbed".

Is this all right? I'm honestly not sure even what is the name of this form. Where can I learn more about it?

Thanks!

Edit: probably "klettern" is the wrong verb here. I'll give some context. The action happens in a bouldering hall with windows and you are not supposed to climb through the window and go outside (you shouldn't). The windows are at the height of a human person's head.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the English sentence. Do you mean to climb on the windowsill? Or climbing across a window? (How can you do this?)

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast -- Yes the situation does seem very odd. Possibly it's a cartoon, video game, or maybe Spiderman is involved somehow. The grammatical issue seems clear though.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, yes, imagine a window that is at the height of your head and you climb through it and go outside

Comment: So, you mean *"You are not allowed to climb **through** the windows"*? This is a completely different sentence than *"The windows cannot be climbed".* First: *"You cannot do something"* is different from *"You are not allowed to do something"* ("You can't walk through solid walls" vs. "You are not allowed to pass the door") Second *"to climb"* is different from *"to climb through"* ("climb a wall" vs. "climb through a hole")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you mean the windows are on a featureless wall so they cannot be climbed e.g. by a burglar. That action is called *erklettern* in German. It's often used in the context of mountain climbing but also in that context of burglary.

> Die Fenster können (von außen) nicht erklettert werden.

Another way to express this thought is

> In die Fenster kann (von außen) nicht eingestiegen werden.

*Einsteigen* into a house means *to break into*.

Comment: not exactly, please see edit

Comment: It's the same verb erklettern, but you have to use the modal dürfen. *Die Fenster dürfen nicht erklettert werden.* or, as typical German signage would put it: *Das Erklettern der Fenster ist verboten.*, or short *Erklettern der Fenster verboten.* or even shorter *Fenster erklettern verboten.*

Comment: I'm marking the answer as accepted because of your comment, if you want add it to the answer. "Die Fenster dürfen nicht erklettert werden", that's the phrase I wanted to learn, thank you

Answer (score 6):

With the edit, the straight-forward translation seems to be:

> Nicht aus den Fenstern klettern!

This would be the appropriate text for a warning sign, to discourage a behavior which one might try otherwise.